# Jenkins pipeline - maven installing dependency projects

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins-pipeline, docker-repository

I am setting up a CI/CD with the following components:
-Bitbucket
-Jenkins
-Docker
-Maven

The desired flow:

1. Committing code to Bitbucket
2. Webhook Jenkins on changes
3. Jenkins pipeline does the following:

   - mvn install 2 projects, SDK+API
   - takes the API jar and build image
   - pushes image to repository
   - deploys service or container to docker

Where I am currently stuck is the following:

I have a PROJECT-A, that has multiple dependency projects that has to be maven installed, before maven installing PROJECT-A and creating an image of it.

Could anybody advise on what is the best practice here?

I have googled an it's say that my only feasible and maintainable option should be using Parent POM. However I failed to understand how do I do that.

```
<modules>
    <module>project1</module>
    <module>project2</module>
    <module>project3</module>
  </modules>
```

Comment: It's unclear what project-A is. Those dependent projects - do you need to build them as well or those should be downloaded from your nexus/artifactory?

Comment: @hakamairi I have project A that has dependent projects B,C etc. I have to maven install them, in order to build project A at the end. They are not deployed on any artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your project would be structured differently with parent pom, where would those additional projects come from? In general mvn install does something different then you mean in this question -

> install: install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally

The best practice here (and missing element) is a package repository. For example your private artifactory or nexus. You would `mvn install` all the packages to it and maven would automatically resolve the dependencies from it basing on its POM and appropriate configuration.